# Java list instance retains its pointer after copying

Tags: java, list, collections, reference

I have following LinkHashMap,

```
LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> test1=new ...
```

in a loop I assign the key value pairs like this,

```
ArrayList<String> temp=new ...
//start iteration
temp.add("some strings")
test1.put("some string", temp);
temp.clear()//temp is cleared for next iteration
```

here *temp* is a temporary list I create just before and add something to it.
But the problem is that when I clear *temp*, the *temp* passed to *test1* is also cleared, that means it is copied by reference. How can I use temp inside test1 still maintaining its reference. I know it is a basic concept, but i am new to java and did not get through all its features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you are not really copying the `List`, `temp`. You are copying the pointer ("reference" in Java lingo).

There are two simple solutions here:

1. Do an actual copy of the `List` using `new ArrayList<String>(temp)` as what you store in the map.
2. Instead of doing `temp.clear()`, do `temp = new ArrayList<String>()`.

The second option is going to perform the best because it's not making a copy of anything; it's simply replacing the reference with a fresh `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `LinkedHashMap.put()` method adds the reference of `List<T>` object (i.e a single *object* is now referenced by `LinkedHashMap` and `ArrayList<String>` references and you can manipulate *that* object via object references - `temp` variable or `test1.get("some strings")`) so do not call the `clear()` method instead create another `List<T>` object.

```
ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<String>();
temp.add("some strings")
test1.put("some string", temp);

temp=new ArrayList<String>();
temp.add("foo");
test2.put("another string",temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone (caller or callee) needs to make a copy of the ArrayList addressed by `temp`, or you need to create a new ArrayList for `temp`.  The second approach is more in keeping with Java "style" (and since the callee is not under your control, probably the only option).

Answer (score 1):

Don´t clear it for the next iteration, just create a new reference. Removing all the elements from the list could become a performance issue while iterating.